# Is there anything that definitely confirms that Svidrigailov actually committed murder in "Crime and Punishment?"

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, crime-and-punishment

Is there any proof that Svidrigailov actually committed murder in *Crime and Punishment*, of either Philip (his servant) or Marfa Petrovna (his wife)?

By proof, I mean either a nuanced passage I might have missed in the actual book, some sort of letter or manuscript by Dostoyevsky, or something else.

Answer (score 17):

Nothing *proves* it. The closest are Dunya's accusations, including her knowledge that he both discussed poison with her, AND went to get that poison.

> "...Не твой револьвер, а Марфы Петровны, **которую ты убил**, злодей! У тебя ничего не было своего в ее доме. Я взяла его, как стала подозревать, на что ты способен."
>
> "**Ты жену отравил, я знаю, ты сам убийца!… Ты мне сам намекал; ты мне говорил об яде**… **я знаю, ты за ним ездил**… у тебя было готово… Это непременно ты…"
>
> "...этот ужасный человек, кажется, и был причиной ее смерти. Говорят, он ее ужасно избил!.."
>
> "Я уверена, что он был причиною смерти покойницы Марфы Петровны..."

English ([translated by Constance Garnett](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2554)):

> "It's not your revolver, it belonged to Marfa Petrovna, **whom you killed**, wretch! There was nothing of yours
>   in her house. I took it when I began to suspect what you were capable of."
>
> "**You poisoned your wife, I know; you are a murderer yourself!...  You hinted it yourself; you talked to me of poison.... I know you went to get it...** you had it in
>   readiness.... It was your doing...."
>
> ". . .  that awful man seems to have been the
>   cause of her death. They say he beat her dreadfully."
>
> "I am convinced that he was the cause of
>   Marfa Petrovna's death."

As well as his own admission he would have easily killed his wife if Dunya told him to:

> Верите ли, я до того тогда врезался, что **скажи она мне: зарежь или отрави Марфу Петровну и женись на мне, — это тотчас же было бы сделано**!
>
> Do you know, I was so wild about her at that time that if she had
>   told me to poison Marfa Petrovna or to cut her throat and to marry herself, it would have been done at once!

---

However, while he drove Philipp to suicide, he didn't kill him.

> "Вы, конечно, Авдотья Романовна, слышали тоже у них ...об истории с человеком Филиппом, умершим от истязаний, лет шесть назад, еще во время крепостного права..."
>
> "...**принудила или, лучше сказать, склонила его к насильственной смерти** беспрерывная система гонений и взысканий господина Свидригайлова."

English:

> "You heard, no doubt, Avdotya Romanovna, when you were with
>   them the story of the servant Philip who died of ill treatment he received six years ago, before the abolition of serfdom."
>
> ". . .  **what drove him, or rather perhaps disposed him, to suicide** was the systematic persecution and severity of Mr. Svidrigaïlov."